# child model accesing the parent model feild in django

Tags: python, html, django

Hello guys I have one query in my Django project.  I Have two models as mentioned below  `UserProfileInfo` and `Post`.  I want to bring `profile_Pic` in the `Post` model so that I can call in HTML.

```
class UserProfileInfo(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='users1')
    portfolio_site = models.URLField(blank=True)
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pics', blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
      

class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(UserProfileInfo, related_name='users', on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the related `UserProfileInfo` model instance and it's field by following the `author` `ForeignKey`

```
post = Post.objects.get()
profile_pic = post.author.profile_pic
profile_pic_url = post.author.profile_pic.url  # For use in your template
```